# How to select a long part of a complicated expression between two symbols inserted for the purpose?

Tags: string-manipulation

I want to select a long expression that spills over into many pages. Using mouse and cursor makes it go really  fast. Is there a way I can insert some characters and instruct Mathematica to pick up only the portion in between the characters?

Specifically imagine I want to select the portion between ZZ and ZZ without unnecessarily counting the number of characters in the string fragment to be extracted.

Original string :

akerkjer3jr3r4b3brk3ZZrb34krbf3kfnef3erefZZvmexckdijo3rj3rf3erferfe3r3f

Output : rb34krbf3kfnef3eref

Comment: There is very likely a good solution to you problem. However, it is impossible to provide it without a concrete example. Please include a portion of your expression into the question, and perhaps also the code used for generating it.

Comment: It is applicable to any expression you imagine. I want the middle portion of the string                     akerkjer3jr3r4b3brk3rb34krbf3kfnef3erefvmexckdijo3rj3rf3erferfe3r3f   without using mouse and cursor

Comment: There is vast difference between "any expression I imagine" and a simple "string" that you provide.

Comment: Thanks for your [edit], However, you are still not showing all the required diligence we expect. What have you tried? Where is your code? Why are the examples of the expected outcome not formatted? I suggest not to vote to re-open this question until the OP has improved the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string:

```
s = "akerkjer3jr3r4b3brk3rb34krbf3kfnef3erefvmexckdijo3rj3rf3erferfe3r\3f";
```

and you want, say the 3 characters in the middle, you first get the length of the string. The middle will be have of it. Then you may use "StringTake" to extract the wanted characters:

```
 n = StringLength[s];
StringTake[s, Round[n/2] + {-1, 1}]

"ef3"
```